# What is $\tan^3 x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, notation

I can't find how to calculate $\tan^3 x$. I don't even know how to use it on a calculator and have no idea what it means. If $\tan x$ is the ascending of the angle $x$, is $\tan^3 x$ the ascending^3. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: tan^3 x = (tan x)^3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation is $\tan^3 x=(\tan x)^3$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: Beware however: $\tan^{-1}(x)\neq (\tan (x))^{-1}$ but rather the inverse function of $\tan x$.

Comment: @dan They write $\tan^3x$ so it doesn't get mistaken for $\tan x^3$, i.e. $\tan(x^3)$.

Comment: Beware however: due to this reason they often us $\arctan x$

Comment: Beware also:  many calculators have the $sin^{-1}$ key very close to the $x^{-1}$ key...Just to be helpful, I'm sure...